# Python - Test if Raw-Input has no entry

Tags: python

I have the silliest question ever probably...

How can I tell if the raw_input never had anything typed into it? (Null)

```
final = raw_input("We will only cube numbers that are divisible by 3?")
if len(final)==0:
    print "You need to type something in..."
else:
    def cube(n):
        return n**3
    def by_three(n):
        if n%3==0:
            return cube(n)
        else:
            return "Sorry Bro. Please enter a number divisible by 3"
    print by_three(int(final))
```

Particularly Line 2... how would I test if final had NO input? The code works fine with anything typed in, but breaks if no entry is provided....

I'm sure it's stupidly simple, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does your code break for you? Testing for `len(final) == 0` is somewhat verbose but should work just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"?

Comment: I suggest `final = final.strip()` to trim any whitespace.

Comment: The error I was receiving was related to my int() conversion at the end.

Comment: @NicholasHazel: Actually, `False == 0` is true (in every version of Python from at least 1.5 to 3.4). However, it's _not_ true that `f == 0` for every falsey value. For example, `'' == 0` is false, even though both `''` and `0` are falsey.

Comment: So what you're saying is that False = 0 = null = "" and they are interchangeable for the most part due to their nonexistant value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No entry results in an empty string; empty strings (like empty containers and numeric zero) tests as boolean false; simply test for `not final`:

```
if not final:
    print "You need to type something in..."
```

You may want to strip the string of all whitespace to avoid breaking when only spaces or tabs are entered:

```
if not final.strip():
    print "You need to type something in..."
```

You still need to verify that the user entered a valid integer, however. You can catch the `ValueError` exception:

```
final = raw_input("We will only cube numbers that are divisible by 3?")
try:
    final = int(final)
except ValueError:
    print "You need to type in a valid integer number!"
else:
    # code to execute when `final` was correctly interpreted as an integer.
```

Comment: @arshajii: It should work just fine; something else is wrong, the code works as advertised.

Comment: I added in your "not final" for the if statement and everything works. Could it be that I'm using a compiler with an older python than 3.3?

Comment: @NicholasHazel: No, both your code and mine have worked since the first version of Python that introduced `raw_input()`, somewhere in the early days.

Comment: Should I just remove converting to an int on my final step...?

Comment: That's right; my point is this question isn't answerable as is because the actual issue cannot be determined.

Comment: @NicholasHazel: Note that in Python 3, you'd use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. Yes, you'd remove the `int()` call from your `by_three()` function call line in that case.

Comment: Wonderful insight. Literally only played with Python for one day now (clearly). I see how powerful it is, but I'm used to PHP and JS syntax. With how simple it is, learning the ropes is a bit tricky :-) THANK YOU for your help!